# Mapa JavaScript de Google se renderiza de nuevo al cambiar de pestaña

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estoy practicando con JavaScript y Google Maps, la intención de mi mini proyecto es crear una clase a la cual le paso parámetros para su configuración, renderice el mapa, y posteriormente con los métodos de la clase se pueda manipular el mapa. Entiendo que esto se puede lograr sin necesidad de usar la clase que estoy programando, sin embargo busco practicar mis habilidades en JavaScript y también crearme un estándar a la hora de trabajar con los mapas.

Pero, tengo dos problemas relacionados uno con otro:

El primero es que cuando quito el foco a la pestaña donde tengo inicializado y renderizado el mapa y vuelvo a darle el foco, el mapa se renderiza de nuevo.

El segundo es que tengo un método dentro de la clase para eliminar el marcador, y al llamarlo este si borra el marcador, sin embargo cuando sucede lo del primer problema que acabo de mencionar, el mapa vuelve a agregar los marcadores que ya había eliminado.

**Clase**

```
class elefmaps {
constructor(config){
    if(typeof config.selector !== 'undefined'){
        this.downfall = false;
    }else{
        console.log('Element ID undefined')
        this.downfall = true;
    }
    
    if(!this.downfall){
        this.map        = false;

        this.element    = document.querySelector(config.selector);
        this.id         = 'map'+this.makeid();
        this.css        = typeof config.css !== 'undefined' && config.css !== ''? config.css : 'height: 50vh;width:100%;';
        this.mapConf    = {
            zoom  : typeof config.zoom == 'undefined' || config.zoom > 14 || config.zoom < 0 || isNaN(config.zoom) ? 5 :  config.zoom,
        }

        this.markers = {};
    }
    this.element.innerHTML = `<div id="${this.id}" style="${this.css}"></div>`;
}
makeid(){
    let r = '',c = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){r += c.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 62));}
    return r;
}
init(lat = null,lng = null){
    if(this.downfall) return false;

    let fnmap = (c)=>{
        let id = this.id,zoom = this.mapConf.zoom;
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), {
                zoom: zoom,
                center: c,
            });
            if(map){
                resolve(map);
            }else{
                reject(map);
            }
        })
    }
    var whenPromiseDone = (m)=>{
        this.map = m;
        this.addMarker(this.initCenter)
    }

    if(lat && lng){
        this.initCenter = {
            lat,lng
        };
        fnmap(this.initCenter).then(whenPromiseDone)
    }else{
        if (typeof navigator.geolocation == 'undefined'){
            this.initCenter = {
                lat: 23.634501,
                lng:  -102.552784
            };
            fnmap(this.initCenter).then(whenPromiseDone)
        }else{
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position)=>{
                this.initCenter = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude, 
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                fnmap(this.initCenter).then(whenPromiseDone);
            });
        }
    }

}

addMarker(position){
    if(!this.map) return false;
    let markerID = 'marker'+this.makeid(), map = this.map;
    this.markers[markerID] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map,
    });
    return markerID;
}
removeMarker(markerID){
    if(!this.map) return false;
    if(!(markerID in this.markers)){
        console.log('This markerID does not exist');
        return false;
    }
    this.markers[markerID].setMap(null);
    delete this.markers[markerID];
}
}
```

**Inicialización**

```
map =  new elefmaps({
          selector: '#modal02 .modal-body',
          zoom: 14,
       })
       map.init();
```

¿Cual es el error? ¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto el problema 1 y con ello también se ha solucionado el segundo problema.

El error era que se volvía a instanciar la clase de Google por lo cual hice una modificación en el método **init()** de mi clase donde agrego una condición y solo en caso de que aun no se haya instanciado anteriormente la clase de Google realizo el proceso.

muestro el método **init()** a continuación ya modificado por si a alguien le sucede lo mismo:

```
init(lat = null,lng = null){
    if(this.downfall) return false;

    let fnmap = (c)=>{
        let id = this.id,zoom = this.mapConf.zoom;
        if(!this.map){
            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), {
                    zoom: zoom,
                    center: c,
                });
                if(map){
                    resolve(map);
                }
            })
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    var whenPromiseDone = (m)=>{
        this.map = m;
        this.addMarker(this.initCenter)
    }

    var maps = false;
    if(lat && lng){
        this.initCenter = {
            lat,lng
        };
        maps = fnmap(this.initCenter);
    }else{
        if (typeof navigator.geolocation == 'undefined'){
            this.initCenter = {
                lat: 23.634501,
                lng:  -102.552784
            };
            maps = fnmap(this.initCenter);
        }else{
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position)=>{
                this.initCenter = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude, 
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                var maps = fnmap(this.initCenter);
                if(typeof maps.then !=='undefined') maps.then(whenPromiseDone);
            });
        }
    }

    if(typeof maps.then !=='undefined') maps.then(whenPromiseDone);

}
```